# Canvas bad rendered after copying from the source canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have two canvas and a select button.

The select button is for changing the scale in the 2nd canvas.

The content of the 1rst canvas is copyed in the 2nd canvas.

When I increase the scale with the select button, the 2nd canvas is resized and scaled perfectly, but his render is bad (the rectangle and the text are blured).

What is the problem ?

Here the source code (you can try it https://jsfiddle.net/0kqqnkmp/) :

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas_second"></canvas>

<br>Choose your scale : <select onchange="change_scale(this);" autocomplete="off">
                            <option>0.5</option>
                            <option selected>1</option>
                            <option>1.5</option>
                            <option>2</option>
                        </select>


<script type="text/javascript">

//The canvas :
c = document.getElementById("canvas");
c.style.border = "solid #000000 1px";

//The second canvas :
c_second = document.getElementById("canvas_second");
c_second.style.border = "solid #000000 1px";

//Define the original width and height canvas :
ORIGINAL_WIDTH_CANVAS = 300;
ORIGINAL_HEIGHT_CANVAS = 300;

c.width = ORIGINAL_WIDTH_CANVAS;
c.height = ORIGINAL_HEIGHT_CANVAS;

c_second.width = ORIGINAL_WIDTH_CANVAS;
c_second.height = ORIGINAL_HEIGHT_CANVAS;

//The canvas context :
ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx_second = c_second.getContext("2d");

//Default scaling
scale = 1;

//Drawing function :
function draw()
{
    //Clear the drawing :
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ORIGINAL_WIDTH_CANVAS, ORIGINAL_HEIGHT_CANVAS);

    //Drawing a red rectangle :
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
    ctx.fillRect(5, 5, 50, 50);

    //Drawing a text :
    ctx.font = "normal bold 20px sans-serif";
    ctx.fillText("Hello world", ORIGINAL_WIDTH_CANVAS-220, ORIGINAL_HEIGHT_CANVAS-10);


    //Clear the drawing on the second canvas :
    ctx_second.clearRect(0, 0, ORIGINAL_WIDTH_CANVAS, ORIGINAL_HEIGHT_CANVAS);

    //Copy drawing on the second canvas :
    ctx_second.drawImage(c, 0, 0);

}

//Function for scaling the second canvas :
function change_scale(this_select)
{   
    //Retrieve the scale value :
    scale = parseFloat(this_select.value);

    //Resize the second canvas :
    c_second.width = ORIGINAL_WIDTH_CANVAS * scale;
    c_second.height = ORIGINAL_HEIGHT_CANVAS * scale;

    //Apply scaling on the second canvas :
    ctx_second.scale(scale, scale);
}


//Draw :
setInterval("draw()", 300);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your blurry results are to be expected when you scale up an image.**

A canvas is effectively a bitmap image. And a bitmap image becomes blurry when scaled up.

So when you scale & draw your bitmap-canvas#1 onto canvas#2 you will get a blurry result.

The fix is to `scale(2,2)` canvas#2 and then reissue the same commands that drew your rectangle & text onto the first canvas.

The nice bit is that `scale` will automatically take care of changing your [x,y] coordinates when redrawing. So you use the exact same [x,y] coordinates that you used to draw into canvas#1.

```
// scale the second canvas
secondContext.scale(2,2);

//Drawing a red rectangle :
secondContext.fillStyle = "#000000";
secondContext.fillRect(5, 5, 50, 50);

//Drawing a text :
secondContext.font = "normal bold 20px sans-serif";
secondContext.fillText("Hello world", ORIGINAL_WIDTH_CANVAS-220, ORIGINAL_HEIGHT_CANVAS-10);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but I can't reissue the same commands for drawing in the canvas#2 because the commands have hundred code lines, that's why I prefer using simply drawImag() for cloning canvas#1 content onto canvas#2. 
Your way is very heavy.

Comment: Fair enough. There's no way to scale a bitmap without it becoming blurry so you have the choice between 1-blurry and 2-heavy. **Fixing heavy:** If your design permits you can wrap your hundred lines of canvas#1 drawing commands inside a function. Then you can use that single function to draw onto canvas#1 and also to redraw onto canvas#2.

Comment: Thank, I have no choice. A separate drawing function is a good idea.

Comment: In your opinion, if I scale canvas#1 like the canvas#2 , the render of the canvas#2 is fixed ?

Comment: Yes, if your design permits, that would be a good fix. The less scaling that has to be done the less blurriness. :-)